# How can I map a vector of strings as argument of a function?

Tags: r, mapping, impala

I want to extract data from an Impala connection, using the tbl() and in_schema() functions from dplyr and implyr. I need to do this for each table separately, and need to specify the table using the in_schema() function and a string to define the table. However, only one single string (ie one table) can be given as an argument, and not a vector of strings. Instead of copy pasting the same code x times, I was wondering if there was a more elegant way of mapping this. See example code for details.

Take this vector of strings for example:

```r
tables <- c("table_a", "table_b", "table_c")
```

To extract one table, code works like this:

```r
table_a <- tbl(impala, in_schema("schema", "table_a"))
```

This doesn't work, which makes sense since only a single string value is expected:

```r
tables <- tbl(impala, in_schema("schema", tables))
```

How can I extract all tables without having to repeat this process for all tables separately?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a loop:

`result_tables <- list()`

`for(t in tables){`

`result_tables[t] <- tbl(impala, in_schema("schema", t))`

`}`

Comment: This is indeed a possible solution, and maybe a case where a for loop is justified over an apply() or map() function. Thanks anyways!